# JQueryUI - Resizable handle lets go while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

I have a jquery ui resizable handler which tends to be quite slow as it is inside a web app. It is possible to drag it slowly and it wont let go, but if it strays off of the handle, it "lets go" and discontinues dragging.

```
$footer.resizable({ // Footer UI resize
    handles: 'n',
    maxHeight: footerHeight,
    minHeight: minFooterHeight - 5,
    stop: function () { // When user has stopped resizing

    $footer.css({ // reset footer width and top position
        'width': '100%',
        'top': 'auto'
    });

    $footerAndStatusbar.show();

    if ($(this).height() < minFooterHeight) { // if the height < #, hide it
        updateHeight(0, $footer);
        $footerAndStatusbar.hide();
    }

    updateHeight(); // update #mainWrap height
},
resize: function (event, ui) {
    $footerContent.height($(this).height() - 35);

    updateHeight(); // On footer resize, calculate and resize
}
}).css('height', Math.ceil((footerHeight + footerHeight / 2) / 2)); ;

$window.resize(function () { // Window resize
    updateHeight();
    editTooltip.tooltip('reposition');
});
```

I realized that the $window (aka $(window) ) resize is being triggered every pixel dragged, (though I'm not sure why) causing a huge performance cut. Basically, my question is, why is it calling the window resize? Whats with the "letting go"

Comment: I commented out some of the fn calls inside the footer resize "resize" and "stop" methods. Still pretty sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `resizestop` instead of `resize`:

```
resizestop: function (event, ui) {
    $footerContent.height($(this).height() - 35);

    updateHeight(); // On footer resize, calculate and resize
}
```

The difference is that `resize` is called every time the mouse moves while dragging. Depending on the complexity of your `updateHeight()` function this could become very slow.

`resizestop` is only called once the resizing has finished - ie. the click/drag ends.

Comment: I thought "stop:" was for that?